# How to add file extension to ignore-on-commit svn changelist?

Tags: svn, changelist

**Situation**

In repository I have some files (mainly results of build), that are versioned, but I shouldn't commit them.

In my opinion this isn't great idea, but it is outside of my control to remove them from repository.

The solution I came up with is using ignore-on-commit changelist (in Tortoise SVN it can be accessed by right clicking item in 'Commit' window and choosing Move to changelist -> ignore-on-commit).

**Question**

Is there a way to put a file extension on that list or do I really have to put all the files on that changelist?

It seems to me, that there is no such option in Tortoise, but maybe it is possible to do in SVN from command line?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by file extension suppose you want to ingore all files which having  extension like  .bak you can put in tortoise properties

[image]

Comment: Sadly this doesn't solve my problem. It works, if you don't want to commit new files with this extension, but if the files are already versioned they will still be listed as changed and ready to commit.

Comment: You can not do much more than you've already did. Global ignore pattern does not works on versioned items. TortoiseSVN has option `Unversion and add to ignore list...`, but that is not applicable to your case, as you can not unversion them. So, all you can do is what you have already done: add every single item to ignore list. If you have large amount of "generated files", you can create shell script to do that for you.

Comment: @IvanJovovic Didn't see your response. I thought so, thanks for the confirmation. ;)